# Multi-Column Combobox And Date Data Type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, date, combobox

I am trying to make a program that calculates for how long someone is awake. The user just needs to input the time he wakes up. But I have come across 2 problems:

1. I need to make a combobox for the user to choose between PM and AM but I don't know how to make a combobox with multiple columns.
2. How can I make calculations with Date type variables? Because I need to get the current time and subtract by the time the user woke up.

Here's the code for now:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim wokeup As Date
    Dim now As Date
    Dim awake As Date

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        now = DateAndTime.TimeOfDay
        ComboBox1.Text = "AM"


    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        wokeup = TextBox1.Text
        Label2.Text = wokeup

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure what you mean by "Multiple Columns" but I am guessing that you just need the user to choose between AM and PM.

```
Combobox1.Items.Add("AM")
Combobox1.Items.Add("PM")
Combobox1DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

2) To subtract time intervals you can use the following:

```
Dim timeAwake as TimeSpan = Date.Now.Subtract(CDate(Textbox1.Text))
```

You may need to add the current date in front of `Textbox1.Text` if the textbox only contains a time.  From `timeAwake`, you can get the total hours awake using `timeAwake.TotalHours`.